# Can I check the value of specific key of php multidimensional array without looping , my php version in 5.4.31

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

my array is...

```
array(2) {
  ["dialog"]=>
   {
    ["enableAll"]=> "true"
    ["loginEnable"]=>"true"
    ["sharingEnable"]=> "false"
    ["keys"]=>
         {
      ["dialogCGkey"]=>"eef163af-3af3-48ee-9cc1-1830ded5e058"
     }
  }
  ["facebook"]=>
  {
    ["enableAll"]=> "true"
    ["loginEnable"]=>"true"
    ["sharingEnable"]=> "false"
    ["keys"]=>
             {
      ["appId"]=>"1406394902958121"
      ["secret"]=> "964594a90ca5140221b43c4e6dfc71c7"
      ["sdkVersion"]=>"v2.0"
    }
  }
}
```

I need to check at least one key "enableAll" has a value "false" ,without looping...

Comment: How would you plan to do this without looping if the first few had TRUE? Don't you have to "loop" through until you find at least one FALSE and THEN you can drop out of the loop?

Comment: Now, if all the "enableAll" have the same value in the array, that is a different story. Is that the case though?

Comment: What's with the random restriction of not looping?

Comment: I've not downvoted this question myself, but if you're wondering why you're getting them, the answer is most likely because "Looping is the correct way to do this". As mentioned in my answer it's certainly possible to hard code it if you know you'll only ever have one or two entries, but in general multi-dimensional arrays should be manipulated using loops.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to obtain a reduced array matching certain criteria:

```
$oneFalseEnableAll = (bool) array_filter($myArray, function($arr) {
    return 'false' === $arr['enableAll'];
});
```

This will leave `$myArray` as the full, original array, with all the `enableAll = true` values still in. If you want to overwrite it with the reduced array, you can just do:

```
$myArray = array_filter($myArray, function($arr) {
    return 'false' === $arr['enableAll'];
});
```

Comment: Note that `empty` is superfluous/misused here, `(bool)array_filter(..)` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Actually that's true, `empty` won't work since it's an expression. I almost used `!!count` (which at least wouldn't have broken). Cast to bool is also a (probably cleaner) solution

Answer (score 0):

Doing this without a loop is a bit hard, you need some sort of recursive function/method. 
But, if you really want no looping and you just need to know if there is a true in there you could try flattening (with spl_lib) it but that might give unexpected results :

```
$output = iterator_to_array(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator($input)), FALSE);
$out = array_search('true', $output);
```

Comment: Aside from him wanting to find `false`, not `true`, will this not find `sharingEnable => false` or `loginEnable => true`?

Comment: true but you can always check the key i guess, combine it with your array_filter and it would work without a loop

Answer (score 0):

```
$hasFalse = array_reduce($array, function ($hasFalse, array $data) {
    return $hasFalse || $data['enableAll'] == 'false';
});
```

This will still loop behind the scenes, but there you go...

Answer (score 0):

If you know your array will only ever contain two entries,  you can hard code it

```
if($arrayName['dialog']['enableAll'] == "false"  || $arrayName['facebook']['enableAll'] == "false")
(
    //At least one value is false
)
```

If you have more than two entries, it's probably time to use a loop. In theory you could hard code as many as you like, but after two or three entries it's less work to write a loop, and the loop is far more maintainable if you need to change how it works later